# Constant step lengths in subgradient method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, subgradient, non-smooth-optimization

I was reading these [notes](https://info.usherbrooke.ca/jpdussault/ROP771H17/subgrad_method_notes.pdf) (if the previous link doesn't work, use [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_notes.pdf)) on the subgradient method, it says that the choice for step sizes (or step lengths) are determined before the algorithm is run, I cannot seem to understand why is this done? What would happen if we use an algorithm similar to what we use in gradient descent, perhaps something like adagrad?

I'm trying to implement an SVM using a mini-batch stochastic gradient descent kind of method, while it does classify data points correctly. The problem is it doesn't quite maximize the slab thickness.

PS: If the link isn't accessible, find the relevant information below

#### Step size rules

1. Constant step size, $\alpha_k = \alpha$ is a positive constant, independent of $k$.
2. Constant step length, $\alpha_k = \gamma/\left|\left| g^{(k)} \right|\right|_2$. This means that $\left|\left| x^{(k+1)}-x^{(k)} \right|\right|_2 = \gamma$.

There are 3 more methods listed, which are square summable but not summable, Nonsummable diminishing, Nonsummable diminishing step lengths.

The notes further say

"The most interesting feature of these choices is that they are determined before the algorithm is run; they do not depend on any data computed during the algorithm. This is very different from the step size rules found in standard descent methods, which very much depend on the current point and search direction."

Comment: Your link is suspicious.

Comment: It is the top result that I get on [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=subgradient+method&oq=), suspicious in what sense?

Comment: In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AduZ.png) sense.

Comment: I'm not sure why that appears to be the case for you, [here](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/1ca8bcd8760a8173697c6b0983ce27ed3677eabc8c29d80dcee5ed0fca9a899a/detection) is a check for this URL. The link seems to open just fine in both brave and firefox for me. Nevertheless, I'll add relevant information to the question itself, to eliminate the need for link altogether.

Comment: 11th grader? Wow! Keep it up dude.

Comment: Ah, actually no. I just didn't update my bio for a while... I'm just a regular student, currently a sophomore pursuing a BTech in AI.

Comment: The "constant step-length" uses $g^{(k)}$, so I honestly don't know what it means about "they do not depend on any data computed during the algorithm", unless they mean line searching algorithms.